# HTML5 Canvas memory leak performance issue

Tags: html, canvas, memory-leaks, html5-canvas, web-worker

I have 2 `canvas` elements, and I draw them in an interval of 125ms.

Both of them must be completely redrawn due to the nature of their work, so it's not possible to re-draw only certain parts of them to increase performance.

**Problem**

When I see in the task manager, the Working Set (Memory) is constantly increasing, based on how fast I'm re-drawing the canvases.

**What I have tried so far**

1. Use clearRect for cleaning (as opposed to set it's width again)
2. Tried deleting the parent div of canvas and recreating the div and loading canvas again in it : This helps slow the the memory increase, but doesn't completely stop it.
3. Reduced different context.fills to as few as possible, but again due to nature of the canvas, it still has a lot of those.

Even if I do all of these things, the Working Set can be high, but shouldn't be constantly increasing.

Any suggestions how to control the memory leak?

---

**Update:**
*The leak isn't in the canvas drawings. I'm using a web-worker to pass on data to the canvas, which is leaking somewhere. Sorry about the confusion!*

Comment: Tough to know without seeing code, although js memory leaks frequently revolve around unremoved event listeners. As far as your overdraw problem goes, you can layer multiple canvas atop one another and only redraw the ones that need it (although the user can only interact with the top layer). I would guess that you are possibly creating a closure in your redraw fn and reassigning your image data to a repeated number of closed-over local vars.

Comment: "Both of them must be completely redrawn due to the nature of their work"
Are you sure you can't parse drawings on more canvases that don't need to be updated every frame ? This way you could just use `drawImage()` which is one the the fastest methods on canvas

Comment: @JaredSmith 's point is worth digging. I'm wondering also if you think about using beginPath : you know that if you don't, the path will grow up ?? Show some code because otherwise it's hard to tell.

Comment: Another advice : try to reduce your app so that it does nothing. You shouldn't have any leak. Now re-enable your features one by one until it leaks.

Comment: @GameAlchemist has a good point - this will allow you to pin point where the actual consumption is coming from and allow you to refactor in order to make things more optimized.

Comment: @JaredSmith: I'm using beginPath and closePath almost everywhere. However, I did read somewhere I should try to reduce that...not too sure about that. I'm only making rectangles and putting fillText, so doing with arcs would only add to more calculations, and that wouldn't be efficient either.

Comment: @rohan Have multiple transparent canvases (e.g. one for the rectangles, one for the fill text). You can obviously break them up even further (eg every textbox gets its own canvas). Position them atop each other via css. On each frame, only redraw the ones that changed. The only problem with this approach is that all touch/mouse events register only on the topmost canvas. If that's not an issue you're golden.

Comment: You can even combine this with drew dahlman's suggestion below. Create a bunch of canvas elements in your javascript: one for each element on the screen plus one more. On each frame update the ones that changed, grab the image data from each, write it to the last canvas, then put that image data on the visible one. Voila: no overdraw, no unnecessary DOM manipulation.

Comment: Again there's not enough information to be able to answer properly, and the O.P. didn't update the post yet. Downvoting.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: I tried your way of disabling everything and turning everything-on one step at a time. Found the issue isn't in canvas, it's somewhere else. Updated the post.

Comment: Ok... You're welcome :-) :-) Not sure this post is still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Using clearRect is your best bet.

Why are you using a 125ms redraw vs requestAnimationFrame ( this uses the native tick, which will also allow for dropping frames and help with performance )

I would avoid removing DOM elements as that is pretty costly.

Memory is always going to go up, I would also check your closures as anything that isn't in a closure will not be auto garbage collected thus leading to more memory use.

Checkout to [statsjs](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/) which will tell you your FPS and give you something to graph against. also [Memory Stats](https://github.com/paulirish/memory-stats.js) which will show you memory consumption.

My guess as to why you're seeing such a spike is that resources aren't being garbage collected and your code could use some optimizations, but without seeing anything that is a big shot in the dark.

Comment: IIRC its not entirely true that closed-over lexical variables can't be garbage collected (although its certainly more problematic). But I suspect you're right about the source of the leak. And you're definitely spot on with RequestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Yeah it's not a HUGE issue, but can cause issues depending on code structure and how things are setup. The closure memory thing is a suggested optimization to make in general as well as dealing with drawing lots of things on canvas.

Comment: Yeah especially something largish like image buffer data.

Comment: @DrewDahlman what do you mean by Memory is always going to go up? Is that normal for canvas? Unfortunately I'm not in a position to share code, but I'll try out this stuff and update the results!

Comment: So Memory goes up until it needs to be cleaned up, which in JS you have no control over other than closures ( The JS engine knows what variables and pieces of code are no longer being needed so it will auto dispose and cleanup for you ) Another thing I might suggest is drawing to a canvas that isn't actually "on screen" first then drawing that data to your data that is part of the DOM. This has performance boosts as well.

Comment: Upvote for rAF -- it really helps in the event of possible frame stacking. As mentioned, buffering to an in-memory-only canvas, [`createElement('canvas')` but don't add it to the DOM] will also help (more helpful with performance than memory usage).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your animation loop in another function that initializes the variables.  This way no variables are created or destroyed in the loop.

```js
var aniTimeout = null;

function wrap() {
  
  var can = document.getElementById('can');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var r = 5;
  var colors = ["#FF0000","#009900","#0000FF","#990099","#00CCCC","#FFCC00"];
  var cLen = colors.length;
  var ms = 125;
  
  function ani() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,50,200);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,50);
    ctx.clearRect(150,0,200,150);
    ctx.clearRect(0,100,200,150);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 190) + 5;
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 140) + 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * cLen)];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    aniTimeout = setTimeout(ani,ms);
  }
  
  ani();
  
}

wrap();
```

```css
#can {
  border:1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
```